# .NET MAUI Doesn't Fill Entire Screen On iOS (Black Bar At Screen Bottom), But Is Fine On Android

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I recently ported an application I wrote for Xamarin Forms over to .NET MAUI. It looks great on Android, but on iOS, there's a black bar at the bottom of the screen that I can't figure out (the background color for the ContentPage is a turquoise variant). Also, the toolbar with the screen title is much taller than usual, probably close to double the height.

An "out of the box" project for .NET MAUI fills the screen correctly, with no black bar at the bottom.

I recently updated everything in the chain - macOS Ventura 13.4.1 so I could install the iOS 16.4 SDK via Xcode 14.3.

I even added a "dummy" page that doesn't do anything other than to present a title and a line of text.

This app was an ordinary Xamarin Forms project before - which is to say, I did not use an *AppShell* in this new MAUI project as the default new project does. I set `MainPage` to:

```cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage());
```

where *MenuPage* is the home screen for the app. Other operations from that home screen simply use Navigation as one would expect.

It doesn't seem like disabling *AppShell* from the project would cause a change to the iOS output, but I'm still learning about .NET MAUI and have seen blog entries and other complaints from other developers. It seems it's still, sadly, a work in progress. Something this basic shouldn't be happening.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this kind of behavior before. It may be useful to see some of the XAML and also parts of the *.csproj* file. Most likely, it's something in the configuration of the app. Did you comment out or remove the `<MauiSplashScreen>`, for example? Side note: There's also no need to use Shell in the ported app. Since you didn't use Shell in the XF app before, I would recommend trying without Shell first, just to get the app running as you expect it to. Anyway, Shell shouldn't be the cause of this.

Comment: Make a new project with maui project template. 1) Does that have same behavior? 2) If you replace its `MainPage = new AppShell();` with `MainPage = new MainPage();` (the template's MainPage directly), does it do the same? 3) How about; `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`? 4) Your app: Which iOS device? One of the tall ones (a model from the last few years), right? 5) If you emulate an older device that is not as tall, does it do the same?

Comment: Thanks for the responses and suggestions! In the interest of time, I've put investigating this particular issue on the back burner. I decided to stick with Xamarin Forms 5, which (while going away by May 2024) is arguably more mature than MAUI. ToolmakerSteve, to answer your questions: 1) A "fresh" MAUI project does not have the same behavior. 2) Haven't tried that but in the current project the result's the same. 3) That's the way it is now. 4) It's a 2nd-Gen iPhone SE, so not one of the taller ones. 5) Haven't done any emulator tests. I try to stick with physical hardware only.

Comment: @smallscreensw Per your screenshot, it shows black bars on top and bottom, for the top bar, you can try to set MainPage `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" ` and `Page.UseSafeArea="False"` to see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing, this is reliably reproducible on iOS when the `<MauiSplashScreen>` is removed (or commented) from the *.csproj* file of the MAUI app.

The following

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <!--<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />-->

    <!-- other stuff -->
</ItemGroup>
```

will lead to:

[image]

So, all you need to do is uncomment or re-add the `<MauiSplashScreen>`, clean the solution and do a full rebuild:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- other stuff -->
</ItemGroup>
```

After that, it should look fine on iOS:

[image]